java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in kotlin android app
I have cloned instagram clone app from the github,
here is the code:-
Manifest.xml:-
     <application
                android:name=".screens.InstagramApp"
        ....>
    <activity android:name=".screens.home.HomeActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    ......
</application>

InstagramApp.kt:-
class InstagramApp : Application() {
    val usersRepo by lazy { FirebaseUsersRepository() }
    val feedPostsRepo by lazy { FirebaseFeedPostsRepository() }
    val notificationsRepo by lazy { FirebaseNotificationsRepository() }
    val authManager by lazy { FirebaseAuthManager() }
    val searchRepo by lazy { FirebaseSearchRepository() }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
        NotificationsCreator(notificationsRepo, usersRepo, feedPostsRepo)
        SearchPostsCreator(searchRepo)
    }
}

HomeActivity:-
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), FeedAdapter.Listener {
    private lateinit var mAdapter: FeedAdapter
    private lateinit var mViewModel: HomeViewModel

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")


        mAdapter = FeedAdapter(this)
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.feed_recycler).adapter = mAdapter
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.feed_recycler).layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        setupAuthGuard { uid ->
            setupBottomNavigation(uid, 0)
            mViewModel = initViewModel()
            mViewModel.init(uid)
            mViewModel.feedPosts.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    mAdapter.updatePosts(it)
                }
            })
            mViewModel.goToCommentsScreen.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let { postId ->
                    CommentsActivity.start(this, postId)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun toggleLike(postId: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "toggleLike: $postId")
        mViewModel.toggleLike(postId)
    }

    override fun loadLikes(postId: String, position: Int) {
        if (mViewModel.getLikes(postId) == null) {
            mViewModel.loadLikes(postId).observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let { postLikes ->
                    mAdapter.updatePostLikes(position, postLikes)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun openComments(postId: String) {
        mViewModel.openComments(postId)
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "HomeActivity"
    }
}

AuthGuard.kt:-
class AuthGuard(private val activity: BaseActivity, f: (String) -> Unit) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        if (auth.currentUser == null) {
            activity.goToLogin()
        } else {
            f(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
            activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }
    }

    private val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
        if (it.currentUser == null) {
            activity.goToLogin()
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
        auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}

fun BaseActivity.setupAuthGuard(f: (String) -> Unit) {
    AuthGuard(this, f)
}

FirebaseUtils.kt:-
val auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val storage: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
fun DatabaseReference.liveData(): LiveData<DataSnapshot> = FirebaseLiveData(this)

The app is crashing with this error:-
AndroidRuntime          com.example.instagramclone           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.instagramclone, PID: 7526
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.common.AuthGuard.<init>(AuthGuard.kt:12)
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.common.AuthGuardKt.setupAuthGuard(AuthGuard.kt:38)
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.instagramclone. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:283)
        at com.example.instagramclone.data.firebase.common.FirebaseUtilsKt.<clinit>(FirebaseUtils.kt:11)
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.common.AuthGuard.<init>(AuthGuard.kt:12) 
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.common.AuthGuardKt.setupAuthGuard(AuthGuard.kt:38) 
        at com.example.instagramclone.screens.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:33) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 

I have tried different ways to solve this problem but still I didn't find any solution in solving this error, In the InstagramApp.kt file I tried to initalize it but still it did not work, I have changed the code compare to the existing github code.
Can someone help me in solving this problem?

It seems like before you actually call FirebaseApp.initializeApp you have components that rely on that initialization that are initialized. I would refactor your code to make sure FirebaseApp.initializeApp is called before any other component.

I have tried FirebaseApp.initializeApp it in the application, you can check the code of the InstagramApp.kt, in the github code it was not there but I had the same error so I tried to move it to the application.

Did you download the google-services.json file from Firebase as suggested in the GitHub README ?

yes I have downloaded it
